# Why Windows synchronizes time even when the Internet is turned off

Tags: windows, windows-10

I do the following on Windows 10

1. turn off the switch Set time automatically
2. change the current year (-1)
3. turn off the Internet
4. turn on the switch Set time automatically

Result - the current year is restored

Is this due to caching? How to clear this cache?

Answer (score 2):

This is controlled by the `w32time` service. If you don't want your clock to sync, you need to stop/disable the service. As soon as Windows finds a valid NTP source, it'll try and sync.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as I described above, I have disconnected from the internet (physically unplugged the cable) so that the w32time service cannot access any ntp-server, including the local network